# How to do merge image layers like imagick does in libvips

Tags: vips

I am using libvips php library i want to merge image layers using libvips. Does any method in libvips for merge the image layers like imagick has as below

```
$img = $img->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `->flatten()` to squash the alpha out of an image. Docs here:

https://libvips.github.io/php-vips/docs/classes/Jcupitt.Vips.ImageAutodoc.html#method_flatten

Unfortunately, phpdoc doesn't let you document optional arguments, so you need to refer to the C docs to see the extra controls:

https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/libvips-conversion.html#vips-flatten

You can remove bands with `unset`, so you can drop alpha from an RGBA image with eg. `unset($image[3])`.

Comment: Is there any way to call direct this method vips_addalpha in php?

Comment: Just do `$image[] = 255;` to append an extra band which is solid 255.